# Sending method as callback function to field object in Rust

Tags: methods, rust, callback, closures, lifetime

I want to implement a `Timer` object, which is owned by `Foo` object and it should call the `Foo` object's method periodically. I just implemented adding callback function (which is executing `Foo` object's method) to the `Timer` as below, but it failed to compile due to conflicting lifetime requirements.

Code (does not containing executing callback function part)

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Timer<'a> {
    callbacks: Mutex<Vec<Box<dyn Fn() + 'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> Timer<'a> {
    fn add(&self, callback: Box<dyn Fn() + 'a>) {
        let mut callbacks = self.callbacks.lock().unwrap();

        callbacks.push(callback);
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    value: usize,
    timer: Timer<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn callback(&self) {
        println!("value is {}", self.value);
    }

    fn process(&self) {
        let callback = || {
            self.callback();
        };

        self.timer.add(Box::new(callback));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::default();

    foo.process();
}
```

failed to compile with below error

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:28:24
   |
28 |           let callback = || {
   |  ________________________^
29 | |             self.callback();
30 | |         };
   | |_________^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 27:5...
  --> src/main.rs:27:5
   |
27 |     fn process(&self) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:28:24
   |
28 |           let callback = || {
   |  ________________________^
29 | |             self.callback();
30 | |         };
   | |_________^
   = note: expected `(&&Foo<'a>,)`
              found `(&&Foo<'a>,)`
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 22:6...
  --> src/main.rs:22:6
   |
22 | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:32:20
   |
32 |         self.timer.add(Box::new(callback));
   |                    ^^^
   = note: expected `&Timer<'_>`
              found `&Timer<'a>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I think the error comes from the `process` method in `Foo` object takes `self` as `&'_` lifetime, but `self.timer` need `&'a` lifetime.

When I added `&'a` lifetime to `self` in `process` and `callback` method as below,

```rust
...

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn callback(&'a self) {
        ...
    }

    fn process(&'a self) {
        ...
    }
}

...
```

Below error occured-

```
error[E0597]: `self` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:29:13
   |
22 | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
28 |         let callback = || {
   |                        -- value captured here
29 |             self.callback();
   |             ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
32 |         self.timer.add(Box::new(callback));
   |                        ------------------ cast requires that `self` is borrowed for `'a`
33 |     }
   |     - `self` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `foo` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:39:5
   |
39 |     foo.process();
   |     ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
40 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `foo` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `foo` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Foo<'_>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you want to create a reference back to `Foo` inside `Timer`, but if `Foo` gets moved or if the `Timer` gets moved out of `Foo` while `Foo` is destroyed, this reference would be invalid. One (naive) way to fix this would be to use a reference counter for `value` and avoid referencing `Foo` directly:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    value: Rc<usize>,
    timer: Timer<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn process(&self) {
        let value_rc = self.value.clone();
        let callback = move || {
            println!("value is {}", *value_rc);
        };

        self.timer.add(Box::new(callback));
    }
}
```

This makes using `value` a bit more difficult and would have a runtime overhead in `Rc` (or `Arc` if multithreaded). A better solution would probably be to split the structs entirely and use the normal lifetime rules like this:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo {
    value: usize,
}

impl Foo {
    fn callback(&self) {
        println!("value is {}", self.value);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::default();
    let timer = Timer::default();

    let callback = || {
        foo.callback();
    };

    timer.add(Box::new(callback));
}
```

This way, Rust will make sure that `foo`, `timer` and `callback` each live long enough, because of the order that they are created and destroyed in inside `main()`.